# NSPrefs "integer" changed why?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I've been using code similar to the following for many years:

```
sMinimumPrice = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kPrefsMinimumPriceRange]
```

Now, however, in 7.1.x it appears this no longer returns an integer, but a long. Is that correct?

If I update my code, will it still run on older versions of the OS?

Comment: welcome to 64 bit Cocoa!

Answer (score 3):

It returns an NSInteger. You should be making no assumptions about the size of that! It is one size on 64-bit and another size on other architectures. And in Xcode 5.1, by default, you will be building for 64-bit as well as the other architectures.

So if `sMinimumPrice` is typed as `int`, that was *always* a mistake, and now it is about to bite you. Declare it as NSInteger and you'll be fine.

Note that thinking of this as a `long` is not going to help, because the size of a `long` is different on 64-bit from other architectures as well. On the other hand, that very fact is useful if your problem is how to find the right NSLog format specifier for an NSInteger: cast the NSInteger to `long` and use `%ld`.

Comment: But doesn't that just move the goalposts? I need an actual "integer" type eventually, that's what the C code actually uses, that's what I stored in there, etc. I suspect I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: "Integer" never meant "int". It always meant NSInteger. If that is not what you wanted, why did you say `integerForKey:` in the first place? If you want complete control of what numeric type goes in and out of NSUserDefaults, call `objectForKey:`. Now you are free to make your own NSNumber wrapping whatever type you really want (e.g. `numberWithInt:` and `intValue`).

Comment: If you know your values will never exceed `INT_MAX`, you should be able to get away with just casting the `NSInteger` to `int`.

Comment: Ok Wevah, that sounds like the solution.